# Installing postgres on Cent OS

Tags: database, postgresql

I am having a hard time getting postgres re-installed on Cent OS 7.2.Here is what I tried.

- Went to [YUM repo of postgres](http://yum.postgresql.org/)
- Created a temporary folder on my machine for the RPM file
- Did `wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm`
- Next I `ran rpm -ivh filename`

But all I am getting is `package pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch is already installed`.

I am fine with the error message, but when I install postgres components using the below command.

```
sudo yum install postgresql95-server.x86_64 postgresql95-contrib.x86_64 postgresql95-devel.x86_64
```

It lists, the details from a different rpm from what I have downloaded, i.e 
9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7

```
Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                              Arch                                   Version                                             Repository                              Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 postgresql95-contrib                                 x86_64                                 9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7                                   pgdg95                                 526 k
 postgresql95-devel                                   x86_64                                 9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7                                   pgdg95                                 1.7 M
 postgresql95-server                                  x86_64                                 9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7                                   pgdg95                                 4.1 M
Installing for dependencies:
 postgresql95                                         x86_64                                 9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7                                   pgdg95                                 1.3 M
 postgresql95-libs                                    x86_64                                 9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7                                   pgdg95                                 218 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
```

When I go ahead with the installation,I am hitting 404 error messages for all the packages.

```
No Presto metadata available for pgdg95
postgresql95-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7 FAILED                                          
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/postgresql95-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found    ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

postgresql95-devel-9.5.1-1PGDG FAILED                                          
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/postgresql95-devel-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found 0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
postgresql95-contrib-9.5.1-1PG FAILED                                          
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/postgresql95-contrib-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: download.postgresql.org; Temporary failure in name resolution"
Trying other mirror.
postgresql95-libs-9.5.1-1PGDG. FAILED                                          
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/postgresql95-libs-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
postgresql95-server-9.5.1-1PGD FAILED                                          
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/postgresql95-server-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Trying other mirror.
```

What am I doing wrong here and why postgres is not getting installed from the rpm that I have downloaded.I am assuming that the rpm version mismatch is the issue.

Comment: what about doing installing `postgresql` without the `95`?

Comment: @Alex : That installs an older version i.e 9.2

Comment: Downvoters..care to comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the fix I did was pretty brute force and might be dumb, but it works anyway.

I did `sudo find / -iname "pgdg95"`.

Ran rm -rf on all the folders and files listed.

Repeated the steps listed above and it installed fine.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492893/unable-to-start-postgresql-9-5-on-centos-7) answer helped me to get it up and running.Also had to change hba.conf.